# Array key does not get interpolated when making object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I'm turning JSON into an array and back into separate JSON objects (it has to do with React and children). The array below works fine, as does putting array elements into vars. But when I try to make an obj from them, the key does not work, it just stays as "myKey" - Why? What is the right way to turn array elements into objects?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());


var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(
function(response){
 return response.json();
    }
).then(function(jsonData){

    result = []

    for(var i in jsonData) {
        result.push([i, jsonData [i]]);
    }

    var myKey = result[0][0];
    var myValue = result[0][1];
    var myJSON = {myKey : myValue}

    console.log(myJSON);


   });

});
```

Comment: `var myJSON = { [myKey]: myValue};`

Comment: That syntax just never occurred to me. Just missed it. I was trying to use more {} but that doesn't work in this context. OK, thanks all.

Comment: Note that it won't work in older JavaScript environments, like old browsers or old phones. In those environments you have to do it with separate assignment statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `myKey` is interpreted as a value, not as a variable.  You need to use the dynamic key syntax, which is:

```
{ [myKey] : myValue }
```

Complete code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());


var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(
function(response){
 return response.json();
    }
).then(function(jsonData){

    result = []

    for(var i in jsonData) {
        result.push([i, jsonData [i]]);
    }

    var myKey = result[0][0];
    var myValue = result[0][1];
    var myJSON = {[myKey] : myValue}

    console.log(myJSON);


   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the key with square brackets.

```
var myJSON = {[myKey] : myValue}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way you can get this working

```
var myJSON = {};
myJson.myKey = myValue;
myJson.myKey2 = myJsonValue2;
..
```

Comment: I believe you'd want `myJson[myKey]` for this version